How to know the size of an aligned type including padding
I have a buffer with chunks that align to the cacheline size, but have  arbitrary length, let's say 100 bytes. It is clear to me that the buffer (vector) elements are aligned on cacheline borders, but then padding must be added for the next chunk to follow, so that it fulfills the alignment requirements as well. How then can I determine, without knowing the alignement requirement, what the size including padding is that an individual chunk must occupy?

(What I'm looking for is the size in bytes of the region denoted by ?)
Live demo:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

#define LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE 64

static constexpr size_t chunk_size_bytes = 100;

struct alignas(LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE) AlignedUint8Chunk
{
   uint8_t data[chunk_size_bytes];
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<AlignedUint8Chunk> buf(2);
    
    // jump to position 30 within the next chunk without knowing LEVEL1_DCACHE_LINESIZE 
    size_t start = 30;
    // size_t stop = start + ???
}


I don't really understand your question. The whole size is just sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) and the padding is sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) - chunk_size_bytes.

Also "jump to position 30 within the next chunk": The chunks and the contents of a chunk are addressed individually. So I don't know what problem you see here: buf[1].data[30]

The comments above are correct. sizeof takes allignment into account. See: demo.

@user17732522 I undestand I framed it confusingly. The size_t start variable will be an index into the whole of the buffer and not know in which chunk it resides, thus I can't just increase the index by one, first I would have to get the index ( which i probably can with modulo but for this I need to know the answer to the question)

@user17732522 Also if sizeof() does the job I'm already happy. I was not sure about that, I thought it would just give me the actual size of the (packed) struct.

@glades Note that something like buf[0].data + stop will be UB if stop is larger than chunk_size_bytes. You will be able to access the elements only by using modulo to retrieve the two relevant index pair anyway. So you could have start/stop simply ignore the padding and just take modulo chunk_size_bytes instead of sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) when accessing, so that it doesn't care about the padding at all.

@glades "(packed) struct": If you use somthing like __attribute__((packed)) or any similar packed attribute, the behavior will be completely up to the compiler. It doesn't need to behave as explained by my comments and the answer then.

Also as a side note: static on a global constant is pointless. A non-inline non-template non-extern const variable at namespace scope automatically has internal linkage in C++ (but not in C).

The region highlighted by ? is simply sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) bytes large, which is 128 in your example:
// passes, when added to your code
static_assert(sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) == 128);

Note that as stated by [dcl.array] p6:

An object of type “array of N U” consists of a contiguously allocated non-empty set of N subobjects of type U, known as the elements of the array, and numbered 0 to N-1.

There is no padding between array elements; the region you have marked "PADDING" is inside of each array element.
To figure out how much "PADDING" there is, you can use:
sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) - chunk_size_bytes
// or
sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk) - sizeof(AlignedUint8Chunk::data)

On a side note, you don't have to (and shouldn't) use macros here; you can define a size constant like:
constexpr std::size_t level1_dcache_linesize = 64;


Thx, interesting, what is this sizeof(type::data) expression?

@glades It's the size of your data member (the array) in struct AlignedUint8Chunk (i.e. 100 in this case).

level1_dcache_linesize should most probably be std::hardware_constructive_interference_size instead.

@PasserBy Interesting but somehow my stdlib hides std::hardware_constructive_interference_size behind an #ifdef __GCC_DESTRUCTIVE_SIZE..
